Creating a flat shadow effect from a circle
I've tried a bit of trig and playing with polar to cartesian coordinates but ultimately getting a bit lost on how to achieve an effect in JS. At the moment I've been using p5.js but open to other options.
Essentially, I'd like to have a circle on the screen, and there is an invisible light casting a shadow off the circle. Eventually I'd like the 'light' and circle location movable, but right now I'm having difficulty just creating the shape of the shadow.

I've Got as far as creating tangents to the circle from a point from the cursor, but not 'casting a shadow' beyond it.
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background("#9B009D");

  const circleCenterX = width / 2;
  const circleCenterY = height / 2;
  const circleRadius = 200;
  

  if (mouseX !== 0 || mouseY !== 0) {
    drawTangentLines(mouseX, mouseY, circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius);
    
  fill("#FF7000");
  noStroke;
  ellipse(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius * 2);
  }
}

function drawTangentLines(pointX, pointY, centerX, centerY, radius) {
  const dx = pointX - centerX;
  const dy = pointY - centerY;
  const directDistance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

  if (directDistance < radius) {
    // If the point is inside the circle, do not draw tangent lines.
    return;
  }

  // Determine angles for the tangent points
  const angleToCenter = atan2(dy, dx);
  const angleFromTangent = acos(radius / directDistance);  // Proper angle to tangent points

  // Calculate tangents
  const angle1 = angleToCenter + angleFromTangent;
  const angle2 = angleToCenter - angleFromTangent;

  // Calculate tangent points on the circle
  const tanPoint1X = centerX + radius * cos(angle1);
  const tanPoint1Y = centerY + radius * sin(angle1);
  const tanPoint2X = centerX + radius * cos(angle2);
  const tanPoint2Y = centerY + radius * sin(angle2);

  // Draw lines from external point to tangent points
  line(pointX, pointY, tanPoint1X, tanPoint1Y);
  line(pointX, pointY, tanPoint2X, tanPoint2Y);
  noStroke();
  fill("white");
  beginShape();
      vertex(pointX, pointY);
      vertex(tanPoint1X, tanPoint1Y);
      vertex(tanPoint2X, tanPoint2Y);
  endShape(CLOSE);
  
  
}

function mouseMoved() {
  redraw();
}


Can you please post enough of the relevant "[mcve]" code that we can see your code working, in order that we can more easily, and accurately, reproduce the problem?

Hey David, sorry, I've updated the code a little bit more but after that I'm truly stuck on where to go next.
There's not so much a definitive issue with the code but that I can't work out what to write / what maths is needed to make the effect in my image vs the effect I have in the code. The code I've written down so far should work once p5.js is imported.

Got there in the end, it's not subtle but just extending the points beyond the canvas with some simple multiplication and filling that area!
    function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background("#9B009D");

  const circleCenterX = width / 2;
  const circleCenterY = height / 2;
  const circleRadius = 200;
  

  if (mouseX !== 0 || mouseY !== 0) {
    drawTangentLines(mouseX, mouseY, circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius);
    
  fill("#FF7000");
  //noStroke;
  ellipse(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius * 2);
  }
}

function drawTangentLines(pointX, pointY, centerX, centerY, radius) {
  const dx = pointX - centerX;
  const dy = pointY - centerY;
  const directDistance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

  if (directDistance < radius) {
    // If the point is inside the circle, do not draw tangent lines.
    return;
  }

  // Determine angles for the tangent points
  const angleToCenter = atan2(dy, dx);
  const angleFromTangent = acos(radius / directDistance);  // Proper angle to tangent points

  // Calculate tangents
  const angle1 = angleToCenter + angleFromTangent;
  const angle2 = angleToCenter - angleFromTangent;

  // Calculate tangent points on the circle
  const tanPoint1X = centerX + radius * cos(angle1);
  const tanPoint1Y = centerY + radius * sin(angle1);
  const tanPoint2X = centerX + radius * cos(angle2);
  const tanPoint2Y = centerY + radius * sin(angle2);
  const diff1X = tanPoint1X - pointX;
  const diff1Y = tanPoint1Y - pointY;
  const diff2X = tanPoint2X - pointX;
  const diff2Y = tanPoint2Y - pointY;

  // Draw lines from external point to tangent points
  line(pointX, pointY, tanPoint1X, tanPoint1Y);
  line(pointX, pointY, tanPoint2X, tanPoint2Y);
  line(tanPoint1X, tanPoint1Y, tanPoint1X+(1000* diff1X), tanPoint1Y+(1000*diff1Y));
    line(tanPoint2X, tanPoint2Y, tanPoint2X+(1000* diff2X), tanPoint2Y+(1000*diff2Y));
  //noStroke();
  fill("white");
  beginShape();
      vertex(tanPoint1X, tanPoint1Y);
      vertex(tanPoint1X+(1000* diff1X),tanPoint1Y+(1000*diff1Y));
      vertex(tanPoint2X+(1000* diff2X),tanPoint2Y+(1000*diff2Y));
      vertex(tanPoint2X, tanPoint2Y);
  endShape(CLOSE);
  
  
}

function mouseMoved() {
  redraw();
}

